# When combo box data selected, fill out textbox with data from Database

Tags: vb.net

I am working on an application and I have a question, I have a Combo box that is bound to a table in my databse, when data is selected in the combo box I would like 'textbox 1' and 'textbox2' to be automatically filled out with data from the table, is this possible? so say for instance when I select 'Richard' on the combo box, 'Richards' 'Address1' and 'Postcode' are filled out in text boxes. I have a sample code that does this but it only seems to work with Int32, see insterted below.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub cmdGetByIdentifier_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdGetByIdentifier.Click
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtIdentifier1.Text) Then
        Dim Identifier As Int32 = 0
        If Int32.TryParse(txtIdentifier1.Text, Identifier) Then
            txtCompanyName1.Text = GetCustomerNameByIdentifier(Identifier)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("'" & txtIdentifier1.Text & "' is not a valid integer.")
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Must enter an identifier to get a company name.")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub cmdGetCustomer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdGetCustomer.Click
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtIdentifier2.Text) Then
        Dim Identifier As Int32 = 0
        If Int32.TryParse(txtIdentifier2.Text, Identifier) Then
            Dim Cust As Customer = GetCustomer(Identifier)
            txtCompanyName2.Text = Cust.Name
            txtContactName2.Text = Cust.ContactName
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("'" & txtIdentifier1.Text & "' is not a valid integer.")
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Must enter an identifier to get a company name.")
    End If

End Sub
End Class


  Module DatabaseOperations
Public Function GetCustomerNameByIdentifier(ByVal Identifier As Int32) As String
    Dim CompanyName As String = ""
    Dim Builder As New OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With {.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0", .DataSource = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Database1.accdb")}
    Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString}
        Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CompanyName FROM Customer WHERE Identifier =@P1"
            Dim NameParameter As New OleDb.OleDbParameter With {.DbType = DbType.Int32, .ParameterName = "P1", .Value = Identifier}
            cmd.Parameters.Add(NameParameter)
            cn.Open()
            CompanyName = CStr(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return CompanyName
End Function
Public Function GetCustomer(ByVal Identifier As Int32) As Customer
    Dim Customer As New Customer

    Dim CompanyName As String = ""
    Dim Builder As New OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With {.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0", .DataSource = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Database1.accdb")}
    Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString}
        Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Identifier, CompanyName,ContactName FROM Customer WHERE Identifier =@P1"
            Dim NameParameter As New OleDb.OleDbParameter With {.DbType = DbType.Int32, .ParameterName = "P1", .Value = Identifier}
            cmd.Parameters.Add(NameParameter)
            cn.Open()
            Dim Reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If Reader.HasRows Then
                Reader.Read()
                Customer.Identifier = Identifier
                Customer.Name = Reader.GetString(1)
                Customer.ContactName = Reader.GetString(2)
            End If
        End Using
    End Using

    Return Customer

End Function
End Module


Public Class Customer
   Public Property Identifier As Int32
   Public Property Name As String
   Public Property ContactName As String
   Public Sub New()
   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why don't you create a procedure which accepts the customer name/ID as a parameter and make a call to the db to get the details of that customer load it into your customer object then map it against your control? Let me know if this is what your after and if you need an example.

Comment: Can anyone help? does my question make sense?

Comment: @Computer yes this sounds similar to what im looking for would you be able to guide me in doing this im pretty new to VB

Answer (score 0):

1.Refer Below Link To Fetch Data from Sql server

2.Create a Function Which Will Return your Data with ID as parameter
[Dataadapter with dataset - sql sever](http://vb.net-informations.com/dataadapter/dataadapter-dataset-sqlserver.htm)

Comment: Im going to be using Microsoft Access as a back end does this matter?

Comment: Anyone any ideas for this question?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure about using Access but in theory what you would do is have a customer object

You would have a SQL Stored Procedure

```
Select * from Customers where id=@ID
...
```

Then a class

```
Public Class Customer
public property ID as Integer
Public property Name as string
public Property Surname as string
....
End Class
```

In your code where you access the data you would have something like

```
Public Function GetCustomerDetailsByID (byval CustomerID as Integer) As Customer ' Or whatever you want to return it as
Dim myCust as New Customer
' Code to access SQL
' Call your SQL procedure called GetCustByID(CustID)

With myCust
 .Name = valueFromYourProcedure
End With

End Function
```

In your client app, you would then call the above, then assign the values to your controls i.e.

```
Dim SingleCustomer as Customer = GetCustomerDetailsByID(1) ' i.e. value form your dropdown

txtBoxName.Text = SingleCustomer.Name
```

Thats a very rough example and isnt fully complete but should give you some idea of how to go about this. Theres a lot of ways to do the above and everyone has their own way so you may need to do some extra research to be comfortable with it.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Computer that's a start certainly, would you mind taking a look at some files on my sky drive, I have a working example, using a similar code to that above but it only works with numbers, Im trying to change the values so it will load text also let me know and ill upload the project files? Thanks

Comment: Go for it i will have a quick look when i get a moment.